# quirks using maven eclipse plugin with WTP

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, eclipse-wtp

I'm using the maven eclipse plugin to generate wtp projects. It mostly works, but there are some strange quirks that I'd like to get rid of:

- I must specify `-Dwtpversion=2.0` each time I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. Otherwise, facet information is not generated.
- The java facet level is set to version 1.4 instead of 6.0, which causes each generated project to have an error `Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet`

How do I get rid of these quirks?

Below is my top-level pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>foo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
  </modules>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
          <additionalProjectFacets>
            <jst.web>3.0</jst.web>
          </additionalProjectFacets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
I fixed it by setting the source and target version of the compiler-plugin to the expected version in a `<plugin-management>` declaration:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Note that using the user properties `maven.compiler.target` and `maven.compiler.souce` instead of the plugin configuration, still makes the eclipse plugin to generate a 1.4 java facet.

Answer (score 1):

You do something wrong. You can use maven-eclipse-plugin (which is discontinued or at least not developed anymore), or use m2eclipse. Not both. Use m2eclipse, but make sure, that you installed m2eclipse extras as well. For some strange reasons these are two update sites, not only one. If you install extras successfully, and use standard web or ejb artifacts, eclipse configuration will be rendered by m2eclipse extras automatically if you use project creation wizard of m2eclipse.

UPDATE:
Sorry, maven eclipse plugin is still alive. Took a look at Issue tracking system.

### First

For the first sight, I have no clue. The [source code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/trunk/maven-eclipse-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/eclipse/EclipsePlugin.java) tells, that it is a simple mojo parameter (that can come from configuration tag). The only thing you can consider is, that configuration is shared inside a POM (according to my experience). So if you use a plugin at the top of the POM, and you use at the bottom as well, the configuration is shared (or the same), which is probably some summary of the two (should be checked in source). So wtpversion may happen to be defined somewhere else inside your POM, or in the [parent POMs](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance). This definition can be overridden by only an environment entry. Quotes from Maven [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html):

> Specifies the expressions used to
>   calculate the value to be injected
>   into this parameter of the Mojo at
>   buildtime. The expression given by
>   default-value is commonly used to
>   refer to specific elements in the POM,
>   such as ${project.resources}, which
>   refers to the list of resources meant
>   to accompany the classes in the
>   resulting JAR file. Of course, the
>   default value need not be an
>   expression but can also be a simple
>   constant like true or 1.5. And for
>   parameters of type String one can mix
>   expressions with literal values, e.g.
>   ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-special.
>   The system property given by
>   expression enables users to override
>   the default value from the command
>   line via -DaSystemProperty=value.
>   NOTE: If neither default-value nor
>   expression are specified, the
>   parameter can only be configured from
>   the POM. The use of '${' and '}' is
>   required to delimit actual expressions
>   which may be evaluated.
>
> ...
>
> The elements in the parent POM that
>   are inherited by its children are:
>
> - dependencies
> - developers and contributors
> - plugin lists
> - reports lists
> - plugin executions with matching ids
> - plugin configuration

### Second

For the second I think you should state jst.java facet version in additionalfacets. Like this: [in this POM](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openejb/trunk/sandbox/openejb-maven-archetypes/quickstart/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml):

```
<additionalProjectFacets>
    <jst.java>5.0</jst.java>
    <jst.ejb>3.0</jst.ejb>
    <jpt.jpa>1.0</jpt.jpa>
</additionalProjectFacets>
```

### Suggestion

M2eclipse has its own problems. On the other hand there is no need to hack your POM just because of Eclipse. So until it fits Your need, You should use m2ecipse + extras instead of maven eclipse plugin.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I'm not asking about using maven from inside eclipse (http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html). I'm asking about generating eclipse projects with maven using the eclipse plugin for maven (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

For the jst.web version the Maven eclipse pluging takes into accound the dependencies of the project. If you have a servlet api dependency defined :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.32</version>
</dependency>
```

You jst.web parameter will be 6.0

```
<faceted-project>
  ...
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="6.0"/>
  ...
</faceted-project>
```